# Cannot remove hd with VBoxManage

Tags: vboxmanage

I am not sure which parameter is missing. Could somebody point to the right direction please?

```
$ VBoxManage storagectl '5771682b-aa14-4bcb-99d5-1c7cd66c528b' --remove
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 5.0.8
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage storagectl       <uuid|vmname>
                            --name <name>
                            [--add ide|sata|scsi|floppy|sas]
                            [--controller LSILogic|LSILogicSAS|BusLogic|
                                          IntelAHCI|PIIX3|PIIX4|ICH6|I82078]
                            [--portcount <1-n>]
                            [--hostiocache on|off]
                            [--bootable on|off]
                            [--rename <name>]
                            [--remove]


Syntax error: Too few parameters
```

Listing devices:

```
UUID:           f62626fd-70fd-4875-a4ee-6003a59c9f84
Parent UUID:    base
State:          locked write
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /.../automation_riak3_1450811382236_67912/box-disk1.vmdk
Storage format: VMDK
Capacity:       10140 MBytes
Encryption:     disabled

UUID:           5771682b-aa14-4bcb-99d5-1c7cd66c528b
Parent UUID:    base
State:          inaccessible
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /.../automation/riak3.second.dsk.vdi
Storage format: VDI
Capacity:       51200 MBytes
Encryption:     disabled
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the output given

```
VBoxManage storagectl       <uuid|vmname>
                            --name <name>
                            [--add ide|sata|scsi|floppy|sas]
                            ....
```

It would appear to me as if `--name <name>` is not optional.

Where the name would be the name of the storage controller I believe.

i.e.

```
--name "SATA Controller"
--name "IDE Controller"
```

*edit*

Here is a [link to the manpage for *VBoxManage storagectl*](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-storagectl)

Comment: I found out that VBoxManage closemedium  disk bddc3512-8615-461c-bcc3-0c1a7d57683c --delete does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Removing unused disks can be done the following way:

```
vboxmanage closemedium  disk bddc3512-8615-461c-bcc3-0c1a7d57683c --delete
```